# Is there a mustache template syntax highlighter or plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, mustache

I'm looking for a Mustache template syntax highlighter / plugin in Eclipse

Does one exist? I don't seem to be finding anything on google, and I don't know how to write my own for Eclipse.

Comment: What is this mustache you speak of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any plugin for supporting [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) Editors and views (see [Eclipse MarketPlace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/apachesolr_search/mustache)).

That leaves only for now using an external supported editor (i.e. outside of Eclipse)

Comment: Nothing as of Jan 2015 either. And [no Handlebars plugin either](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/handlebars).

Comment: This is surprising.  I'm going to fix this.

Comment: @JosefSalyer Did you fix it?

Answer (score 33):

Although not perfect, you can use Eclipse and set MUSTACHE template files to HTML.

1. Go to Eclipse->Preferences->General->Content_Types
2. Edit CONTENT_TYPE to add a file association of .mustache
3. Go to Eclipse->Preferences->General->Editor->File_Associations
4. You should see the default HTML editors already set.  If not, add a .mustache editor of your choice.  I used HTML_EDITOR.

Although it won't syntax highlight the {{ }}, it's still easier to read.

Comment: +1 This was a huge help for me. But there is a caveat: This will only help people using Mustache for HTML templates. You can use Mustache to output other kinds of content, too.

Comment: I tried to do this and I somehow set the Java compiler to show syntax errors. Now I have a bunch of red underlines everywhere in my mustache files. Anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: @AndrewEnsley I recommend the `.htmm` extension. "HyperText Markup Mustache" ={D